# How to remove "auto increment" from a MSSQL table via liquibase

Tags: java, sql-server, liquibase, auto-increment

Looking in the [Liquibase documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_auto_increment.html) I can see a ChangeSet action for `addAutoIncrement`... however the opposite of that (`dropAutoIncrement` ?) does not seem to exist.

### The Problem

In a database table `Widget`, I have switched from a single-field, auto-increment id (`WidgetId`) to a composite id (over 3 columns). Adding a new primary index over 3 columns (`WidgetId`, `WidgetType`, `OrderId`) seems to work fine.

Under the new design, my application may explicitly set the `WidgetId` (e.g.: 1, 2, 3... etc)

However, I am getting the following error when my application inserts new data into the table:

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Widget' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

### Type: int (auto increment)

When I look at the table `Wigdets`, the type of `widgetId` is `int (auto increment)` - this is a legacy from the previous database design (with a database generated unique id) and I presume this is the issue here.

Given the database is MS-SQL and we use liquibase, how can I remove the "auto increment" from `WidgetId`?

I would like some liquibase xml that codes in here:

```
    <changeSet author="steve" id="remove-auto-increment-from-widget-id">

    </changeSet>
```

Our backend is: Liquibase 3.8.1 / JPA / Java / MS-SQL

Comment: Your WidgetId was created as IDENTITY and there is no way to change it. You can add another column, update it with the data from WidgetId, drop old column and rename new column as WidgetId

Comment: @sepupic ok, thanks. What about enabling IDENTITY_INSERT on the Table, is that a good idea / bad idea?

Comment: That is exactly what I said. It's "on the table". In the CREATE TABLE Widget IDENTITY was used in WidgetId definition. And it cannot be changed. At table level

Answer (score 2):

I did it using the `<modifyDataType>` tag. That should remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` from the column.

```
<modifyDataType tableName="widget" columnName="widget_id" newDataType="int"/>
```

Comment: This worked great for me, and very simple!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
- objectQuotingStrategy: ${objectQuotingStrategy}
- changeSet:
    id: 1593006068007-1
    author: akoylu (generated)
    preConditions:
        not:
            dbms:
                type: h2
        onFail: MARK_RAN
    changes:
    - renameColumn:
        oldColumnName: id
        newColumnName: oldId
        tableName: Wigdets
    - addColumn:
        columns:
          - column:
              name: id
              type: int
        tableName: Wigdets
    - sql:
        sql: |
            update Wigdets set id = oldId;
    - dropPrimaryKey:
        tableName: Wigdets
    - addNotNullConstraint:
        columnDataType: int
        columnName: id
        tableName: Wigdets
    - addPrimaryKey:
        columnNames: id
        constraintName: WigdetsPK
        tableName: Wigdets
    - dropColumn:
          columnName: oldId
          tableName: Wigdets
```

Script renames id column to oldId to transfer data, updates newly added column with existing data, drops primary key, adds not null constraint, adds primary key to newly added column and finally removes old id column.